# Product options limited to only two when paying via Paypal

Tags: html, csv, paypal

Team,
Can anyone help with this?
Simply, I am passing options with a particular product within html like so:-

```
<input type='hidden' name='on0_1' value='Buckle Colour'>
<input type='hidden' name='os0_1' value='Chrome'>
<input type='hidden' name='on1_1' value='Size (mm)'>
<input type='hidden' name='os1_1' value='14'>
<input type='hidden' name='on2_1' value='Colour'>
<input type='hidden' name='os2_1' value='Black '>
```

However, when the payment goes through and I use the Download History to pull down the order information, I only see two options in the downloaded csv file (Under History - Download History).
It's difficult to cut and paste this but below is a section, including the header row, from the resulting csv file.
I really need to be able to pull down all product options.
Is the problem at the Download History end? Is there a way of getting all product options into the csv file?

Thanks
AJ

VAT     Option 1 Name   Option 1 Value  Option 2 Name   Option 2 Value  Auction Site    Buyer ID    Item URL
0
    Buckle Colour   Chrome  Size (mm)   14mm

Answer (score 0):

Payments Standard only supports 2 options sadly. [HTML Reference](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HF080O3)

Comment: But in the html link you provide it states; "You can specify a maximum of 7 option selections (6 with Subscribe buttons) by incrementing the option selection index (os0 through os6). You can implement up to 5 option selections as dropdown menus and up to 2 option selections as test boxes. " So what is the point in being able to specify these if you can't then download the information passed? Thanks AJ

Comment: I guess they expanded it on me. It's been a long time since I used Payments Basic. It doesn't surprise me their other systems haven't caught up. I wonder, tho, if you could use [GetTransactionDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) to get the data you need. In theory it should pass that back.